# Adjusting Text to the Right side using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have to make a webpage of food ordering. In the left side, **navigation** is defined, and in the  center there is a tag line quote written in

> div class="main_content"

which will be in the center of the webpage and in the

> div class="right"

there is several other line is written which will be in the right upside like People Cards in google search.

Help me to adjust it using CSS. Below is my Html and CSS code.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #f3f5f9;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper .sidebar {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #FDFDFB;
  padding: 30px 0px;
  position: fixed;
}

.wrapper .sidebar h2 {
  color: rgb(82, 17, 17);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li {
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bdb8d7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a {
  color: #bdb8d7;
  display: block;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a .fas {
  width: 25px;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li:hover {
  background-color: #594f8d;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}

.wrapper .main_content {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.wrapper .main_content .header {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #717171;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e4e8;
}

.wrapper .main_content .info {
  margin: 20px;
  color: #717171;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.wrapper .main_content .info div {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.right {
  width: 48%;
  float: left;
  padding: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <h2>Loren<br>Ipsum</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-about"></i>About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-service"></i>Service</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-cuisine"></i>Cuisine</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-gallery"></i>Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-contact"></i>Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-book"></i>Book</a></li>
    </ul>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Cart">
  </div>


  <div class="main_content">
    <div class="info"> What are you having for Lunch?</div>

    <div class="right"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod incidunt ut laoreet et</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is completely unclear what your problem is.

Comment: Remove the float , you better use `flex` box .. give `info` `flex:1` to take the maximum available space .. the parent `main_content` should have  `display: flex` .

Comment: Hossam, how to adjust div class="info" to the right relative position?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the div in container div and adjust in to float right or left.
Make sure your div width is set to 100%.